# Random numbers that follow a linear drop distribution in Python

Tags: python, random, frequency-distribution

I'd like to generate random numbers that follow a dropping linear frequency distribution, take n=1-x for an example.

The numpy library however seems to offer only more complex distributions.

Comment: Welcome to SO Martin! The community will gladly help you with coding problems you encounter as you work on an issue. However, you need to provide the code that you have written and the problem you are encountering. Normally, we don't write it for you.

Comment: The problem is so fundamental, that I can't even Start coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out you can totally use `random.triangular(0,1,0)` for this. See documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

> random.triangular(low, high, mode)
>
> Return a random floating point number N such that low <= N <= high and with the specified mode between those bounds.

Histogram made with `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
bins = [0.1 * i for i in range(12)]
plt.hist([random.triangular(0,1,0) for i in range(2500)], bins)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For denormalized PDF with density

```
1-x, in the range [0...1)
```

normalization constant is 1/2

CDF is equal to `2x-x^2`

Thus, sampling is quite obvious

```
r = 1.0 - math.sqrt(random.random())
```

Sample program produced pretty much the same plot

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [0.1 * i for i in range(12)]
plt.hist([(1.0 - math.sqrt(random.random())) for k in range(10000)], bins)
plt.show()
```

UPDATE

let's denote `S` to be an integral, and `S_a^b` is definite integral from `a` to `b`.

So

```
Denormalized PDF(x) = 1-x
```

Normalization:

```
N = S_0^1 (1-x) dx = 1/2
```

Thus, normalized PDF

```
PDF(x) = 2*(1-x)
```

Let's compute CDF

```
CDF(x) = S_0^x PDF(x) dx = 2x - x*x
```

Checking: `CDF(0) = 0`, `CDF(1) = 1`

Sampling is via inverse CDF method, by solving for `x`

```
CDF(x) = U(0,1)
```

where `U(0,1)` is uniform random in [0,1)

This is simple quadratic equation with solution

```
x = 1 - sqrt(1 - U(0,1)) = 1 - sqrt(U(0,1))
```

which translated directly into Python code

Comment: May you explain how get formula for obtain?